# Getting react tsc errors when I'm not even writing react

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, transpiler

I'm learning typescript, and when I transpiled the code with `npx tsc index.ts` it threw 10 errors, however, it still transpiled the file.

[image: console error]

I tried moving the folder to a new location to see if tsc is in conflict with any react file I have in there
I also left the ts file empty and I get the same error

typescript code:

```
const greeting: string = "Hello world";

console.log(greeting);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "ema4hhh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "tsc index.ts",
    "watch": "tsc index.ts -w"
  }
}
```

thank you

Comment: Do you maybe have a `tsconfig.json` file in the folder which has React specific options/configurations?

Comment: Nop, I don't have a config file, only package.json, index.ts and node_modules

Comment: Could you share your `package.json` file as well?

Comment: I just edited the question with the package.json

Comment: With the provided information, setup seems OK to me. I just noticed in the image that the node_modules are two levels up (`../..`). Is your directory within some other nodejs project that might have `tsconfig.json` file? I would also suggest changing the package.name to something else to avoid collision with `typescript` package.

Comment: I tried moving all the folder to a new directory without anything about programming, but it doesn't seem to work, and this is the first time using typescript so I don't have a tsconfig.json in my computer

Answer (score 0):

Asking in another forum, someone suggested to reinstall react globally, which I didn't think it was the problem because I wasn't importing it, but it worked